# Custom Delegate method not working in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode10.1

// userprofileform.h(viewcontroller)

```
@class UserProfileForm;             
@protocol UserProfileFormDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) UserProfileFormDelegateReload: (UserProfileForm *) sender;

@end

@interface UserProfileForm : OTSFormViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate>
@property(nonatomic,assign) id <UserProfileFormDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

//userprofileform.m

```
#import "UserProfileForm.h"

@implementation UserProfileForm

- (void)endFlow:(id)sender {
     [self.delegate UserProfileFormDelegateReload:self];
     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

//shopprofilecontroller.h

```
#import "UserProfileForm.h"

@interface ShopProfileController : OTSViewController <UserProfileFormDelegate>

@end
```

//shoprofilecontroller.m

```
@implementation ShopProfileController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Business";

    UserProfileForm * userProfileForm = [[UserProfileForm alloc] init];
    userProfileForm.delegate = self;
}

-(void)UserProfileFormDelegateReload:(UserProfileForm *)sender{
    NSLog(@"delegates fired");
}
```

but the delegate method is not called upon popping the UserProfileForm.
I don't know why is it not firing. I have tried NSNotifications and it did not fire too.

Comment: Btw, under ARC which you are probably using, the `delegate` should be `weak`, not `assign`. Also in your code `userProfileForm` is never stored so it should be deallocated immeditely.

Comment: when i use weak the xcode is yelling at me with this "Cannot synthesize weak property in file using manual reference counting"

Comment: Why are you using manual reference counting?

Comment: its an old project i am trying to add a new feature. and i found that the button that triggers the push ViewController action is actually in a category of the class shopprofilecontroller so how should i implement the delegates methosd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried your code and it worked fine.
The only thing I changed was at the end of `viewDidLoad()` of `ShopProfileController` I put the following line:

```
[userProfileForm endFlow:self];
```

So your delegate implementation should be correct. 
Set a breakpoint within your `endFlow()` method, I bet its not getting called.

Comment: I checked its firing but still delegates are not getting called

Comment: Thats interesting, can you confirm that at `[self.delegate UserProfileFormDelegateReload:self];` the `self.delegate` still points to the correct object? (You can compare the pointer of `self.delegate` with the pointer of `self` within the `viewDidLoad()` of  `ShopProfileController`, they should match)

Comment: _delegate id 0x0 0x0000000000000000 this what it shows in self.delegate

Comment: Ok that explains why your delegate wont get triggered (but kinda weird that it doesn't crash?). Can you check the pointer of `self` and `userProfileForm.delegate` right after this line: `userProfileForm.delegate = self;` ?

Comment: userProfileForm.delegate = self; is in shopProfileController. upon loading shopProfileController self is pointing to <ShopProfileController: 0x7fc0f01ba600>

Comment: ok it looks like that the `delegate` variable of the `userProfileForm` object somehow gets reseted to nil (=0x00000000). You now need to figure out at which point this happens, maybe you see then why it is happening and then be able to fix it

Comment: You can also try to add the `deinit` method to your `ShopProfileController` to see if it gets deallocated while you present the `UserProfileForm`

Comment: its (=0x00000000) from the very 1st encounter of [self.delegate UserProfileFormDelegateReload:self]; any ideas why?

Comment: Put this function in your `ShopProfileController`: 
`- (void)dealloc
{
  NSLog(@"dealloced");
}`

Does it get triggered if you show your `UserProfileForm` ?

Comment: ok at least thats a good thing, so your `ShopProfileController` does not get deallocated. Did you check if the pointer of `userProfileForm` in `ShopProfileController. viewDidLoad` is the same as the pointer of `self` in `UserProfileForm`? Just to double check if these are really the same objects.

Comment: Yes both are the same.

Comment: Okay thats also good. But I fear I can't help you any further since I'm not very familiar with projects without ARC (and I used objective-c a long time ago ). It also could be that the problem is in a code section that you didn't share here. Maybe its also just a bug of xcode and cleaning the `DerivedData` folder might fix the issue 

Comment: sry that I couldn't help you more, hope you find the issue

Comment: actually i did. i used different object for pushing the vc thats why the delegates were nil.